# How to restore data from SQL Server 2005 in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2000, restore

how can we get the restore in sql server 2000 of sql server 2005 data

Answer (score 1):

You can't restore  data from sql 2005 to 2000 only if you generate scripts with sql server 2000 compatibility. If you want create and restore backup can't do.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found myself in a similar position on a client site.  I came across [an article on the MSDN SQL Server Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/46e3ecf9-6eab-4aa0-9453-11e7269efb6e/) (second response from top) with a detailed walk-through on this issue.

I ran into a few issues with scripting users & had to hack my way through it a little bit, but it was a great starting point for me.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible.  You can't go from 2005 to 2000, what you would have to do is install SQL 2005 Express then restore to that and you should be able to manage the backup from there.

If you only need the database structure you can generate scripts for the entire database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In the Properties window of the SQL 2005 Database you can set the compatibility level of that database to SQL 2000. Then perform the backup and then restore to SQL 2000.
If you don't want change the compatibilty level of your original database, just do a backup first and restore the database as a dummy in SQL 2005 and set that database's compatibility level.

[alt text http://img411.imageshack.us/img411/8541/clipboard01lro.jpg](http://img411.imageshack.us/img411/8541/clipboard01lro.jpg)

Comment: I am under the impression that this is not going to work. The compatibility mode is for how the server behaves in response to commands and script, not for the internal structure of files.

Answer (score 0):

Use RedGate SQL Compare and RedGate SQL Data Compare to push the tables and data from SQL 2005 to SQL 2000.

You may be able to script the whole database from SQL 2000 compatibility mode, but getting the data requires something besides a backup and a restore. You could try bulk saving and bulk loading data, too...